# Debugging Python Code, Visual Studio Code, Virtual Enviroments

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been trying to configure the debugger on vscode for debugging python code. Below is the launch.json config and following are the settings.json and externalTerminal (launch.json) config, respectively.

[image: Launch.json Python Config using integrated terminal]

[image: Settings.json]

I have read through the documentation but I am afraid I am not able to understand it. From what I read on there, I need to set up my external terminal configuration as the integrated terminal isn't capable of accepting inputs(yet).

[image: Launch.json-External Terminal Config]

I am using virtualenvs for my project and I have them in the path: usr/Projects/VirtualEnvs. All my venvs reside in there. I tried to set `"python.pythonPath": "/usr/Projects/VirtualEnvs/myVenv/bin/python3.6"` which doesn't seem to work. Could anyone help me out or at least point me in the right direction (would be a good learning experience)? Please let me know if my question isn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

My mistake: The python interpreter was not set for the script I was debugging, and since I was using a venv with different Python version, I was thinking that maybe I'd have to somehow set it to that version of the Python interpreter!

How I came to the solution?: Today, while studying and getting stuck with a problem, I noticed that near my shebang was line that said 'Set as interpreter'. I clicked that and VSCode told me that it was now using Python 3.6.1 as the interpreter, that kind of got me excited. Just to be sure I did a google search and found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xRz3Cj86E4). That, very quickly, helped me understand my problem that firstly the interpreter wasn't set and secondly, I was running the debugger from the wrong file! 

             `"program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"`

This setting takes care of which folder and what file for you!

For the External Terminal configuration, a new terminal window pops up and you can supply args to your `input` statement and watch as the debugger goes step by step!